# Copy a database file in android

Tags: android, database, permissions, copy

I am developing an android application that copies a database file from `/data/data/com.example/database.db`

But it give me an access denied file

> EACCES permission denied

Could anybody help me how to permit the access?

Comment: are you  trying to steal a db from another app?

Comment: I think possible with rooted mobiles only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are copying you probably need the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your manifest.

Add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

(see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html for how to use the uses-permission tag in the manifest)

Add it and let us know if you still get the error.